# How to use StreamJsonRpc library in C# passing strings

Tags: c#, json-rpc

I am new to C# environment, been using java for over a decade, now mostly kotlin.
I am trying to setup C# json-rpc server using this library. I can hook it up to TCP (Stream) or HTTP (WebSocket), but I need api, where rather than handling whole communication for me, I want to pass string, which represents json-rpc request and make library do the call (mapping to correct call) and then return me string, representing json-rpc response to send. Reason for that is, I am having request queue, that is handling requests on different thread (and some not).

https://github.com/microsoft/vs-streamjsonrpc

It might be also matter of implementing my own transport layer/scheduler as alternative to Stream/Websocket, but that seems too deep to dig into, when not knowing whole ecosystem and platform at all.